# Why do flash messages stop working if I enable cookie secure to true

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

For some reason if I use cookie: {secure: true} on my local machine. My flash messages don't show up.

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'randomSecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  //cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

I know that in https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session it mentions that cookie true only works on https sites but why does it affect the flash messages?